# Finding the Limit of a Sinusoidal Expression

Tags: limits

My question regards evaluating the following limit (I apologize for poor formatting, as I'm new to the website):

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} (x\sin(1/x))$$

My teacher has told me that we are to use L'Hopital's rule in order to evaluate this limit; however, I do not know how to turn this limit into 0/0 or infinity/infinity form. Any advice or suggestions to reach this stage—or advice as to how else to solve the limit—would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac 1x}$$ Now use $y=\frac 1x$ and consider the problem of the limit of $\frac{\sin(y)}y$ when $y\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint write it as $\frac{sin(1/x)}{1/x}$ and go for LH rule

Answer (score 0):

Use that
$$x=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac 1x}$$
for $x\not=0$ to have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac 1x\right)}{\dfrac 1x}$$